# Increasing the height of EditText

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-edittext

Please have a look at the following XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Talk" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/speaker_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_simple" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adTalk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        googleads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This generated the following UI

[image]

As you can see, the `EditText` height is small. I want the the text to have a height, until it meet the `AdView`. I height I am expecting is marked in red coloured line at the right side of the image.

I have tried number of things to do.

1. setting the height to `match_parent` -  This didn't worked because it took out the space left for ads.
2. Changing the number of lines - This is not good because in different phones, the `EditText` will have different height.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Changing the android:layout_height="wrap_content" with android:layout_height="fill_parent" or "match_parent" doesn't solve the problem? Moreover, there is no need to use LinearLayout when you are using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your LinerarLayout like this..

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
    android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:linksClickable="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This gives ClassCastException: 11-19 07:27:55.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ace.voicebuddy/com.ace.voicebuddy.Talk}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence class cast is not because of layout..it is in your code..post your code once with logcat..

Answer (score 0):

Please use `android:layout_weight="1"` for the EditText after `android:layout_height` and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this snippet.

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         >
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/textField"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:linksClickable="true"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:gravity="top"
>         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
>          >
>
>         <requestFocus />
>     </EditText>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: This gives ClassCastException: 11-19 07:27:55.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ace.voicebuddy/com.ace.voicebuddy.Talk}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: Make sure you cast to the right class when calling findViewById(). I assume your code should be like this: `AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adTalk);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
            android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adTalk"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            googleads:adSize="BANNER" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            googleads:adUnitId="a1528a76339cc88"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Talk" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adTalk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="a1528a76339cc88" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/speaker_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_simple" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
        android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:linksClickable="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```